# How to display Canvas with ipycanvas on Jupyterhub?

Tags: display, jupyterhub, ipycanvas

The following code works fine on my local machine/environment:

```
from ipycanvas import Canvas
canvas = Canvas(width=300, height=300)
display(canvas)
```

But using `jupyterhub` installed on VM on GCP it does no longer display the canvas.

What is missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ipycanvas is a package which needs to be installed in the same environment as the jupyterlab instance. Additionally, you need to have nodejs installed, and you need to enable the jupyterlab ipycanvas widget.

These are all covered in the [ipycanvas installation instructions](https://ipycanvas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html):

> #### Using conda
>
> ```bash
> conda install -c conda-forge ipycanvas
> ```
>
> #### JupyterLab extension
>
> If you have JupyterLab, you will also need to install the JupyterLab extension. In order to install the JupyterLab extension, you will need npm to be installed. You can easily install npm with conda:
>
> ```bash
> conda install -c conda-forge nodejs
> ```
>
> Then you can install the JupyterLab extension:
>
> ```bash
> jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager ipycanvas
> ```

Since you mention that you're on jupyterhub, if you're on a cluster and you're not the administrator, it's possible you don't have the permissions to do this. If that's the case, reach out to your cluster administrator - it's possible they don't allow users to enable extensions.

Comment: It displays after doing all this (with `sudo` commands and after restarting the server..). Should I do the same thing with `ipyevents` too because now this one too is not working.

Comment: Yeah you’ll have to install every plug-in that you want on the server

Comment: You're right. I actually did all this locally but completely forgot about it during deployment lol. Thanks!